# Hyper-V / Server-Client-Model / Download VM from server to locale machine / VM HUB

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v

I have to realise a solution for a software instruction room.

I have the following vision:

- There are 9 Clients, all of them run Windows 10 Pro with Hyper-V.
- There is a Server (Win Ser 2016 maybe), on this server are multiple different VM storen in Hyper-V (for different softare).
- I configure the VM on my server with a new software, all clients download the VM and run it locale.
- After that I can delete the VM on the client again but it still remains on the server, ready if I need to instruct this software again.
- My main point is, that there is only one VM on the server for each software.
- I don't want a standard Server-Client model, where the clients remotedesktop into a VM, because I would need to have 9 VMs per software. Also the VMs have to run on the client for performance.

Like I said this Server should be something like a VM HUB and my clients download from this Server. First of all, I don't even know if there is an easy way to realise that and if it is, how could I manage the licenses of my VMs (VMs are mostly Windows 7)?

Had anyone a simmalar project or a link to a blog wich explains a possible solution?

EDIT:

I also thought about a export inport method, where i take the VM, put it on a share and download it with the client with a script but maybe there is a less difficult solution. (User friendy for the instructors)

EDIT 2:

Docker could be a solution. Problem is that it's even more unfriendly for our instructors. Thats why i wan't a complete VM solution and not only software share. Also our software has to be licenced.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use [Docker containers](https://www.docker.com/) ? Containers are smaller than VMs, Docker does download stocked containers exactly as you ask for, and Windows Server 2016 will [support Docker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/quick_start_windows_server) (the beta already does but not perfectly).

Comment: @harrymc Yea, I also thought about docker. The problem is that it has to be user friendly for our instructors. Hyper-V is allready on the Line of a simple solution, but thanks for the advise. Maybe im still gonna take a look at it.

Comment: @harrymc I just noticed, that Docker for Windows does make use of Hyper-V. I think that could work, the only thing that bothers me is the pricing. And what about windows 7 licensed of my VMs? An idea how i could handle those?

Comment: In theory, containers encapsulate applications, not operating systems, where local system services are furnished by the local OS. Therefore you will have no licensing issues.

Comment: @harrymc I see, I just informed myself about Docker and it looks like it was not what i thought it would be. I think it would work and I could ship our software to the different PCs. The problems begin when i have to configure those. The Programs have certain configurations which won't come with an container and even if, It will be way to complicated to register a new software for an instructor. That's why i went for the full VM solution.

Comment: I have also only looked at containers but didn't use them yet, nor have I installed the Win Server 2016 beta. But I'm not sure that there are any configurations that cannot be included. If Microsoft can package monsters such as SQL Server or IIS in containers, I don't think there are any limits. Or maybe you could use shared files on the server for those. In any case, for a configuration change you could replace the stocked container.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, MS's solution can not allow us transfer the VM to local.

You may try the solution from VMWare, they have a feature called local mode, which is similar to your requirement.

[Running VMware View Client with Local Mode](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2032741)

Comment: Not a bad idea but i think it is too complicated for my use. Also i would still need 9VMs per software.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [Docker containers](https://www.docker.com/). Containers are smaller than VMs, Docker does download stocked containers exactly as you ask for, and Windows Server 2016 will [support Docker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/quick_start_windows_server) (the beta already does but not perfectly)

Containers encapsulate applications, not operating systems, where local system services are furnished by the local OS, so you will have no licensing issues.

When configuration changes happen, you could replace the stocked container
or maybe use shared files on the server.
If Microsoft can package monsters such as SQL Server or IIS in containers, I don't think there are any limits to what can be packaged.